# fluentassertion won't compile

Tags: c#, compilation, fluent-assertions, fact

I am obviously missing some assembly or reference to make this work, it may be `fluent assertions` or it may be `Microsoft.Team Foundation.Warehouse`. Neither of which I am sure how to use / add as references (well I am sure how to install fluent assertions, it just did nothing!).

I found [the code below online](https://gist.github.com/ReitenSchnell/5998938) and I would like to use it but it is missing some components, rather than say any more here is a screen shot - I have installed fluent assertions library in order to try to get a compile (I believe "Should()" is s component of fluent assertions)

it seems to be upset at these two keywords `[Fact]` and `Should()` is this an easy win for someone to offer a hand?

[image]

The hover message says "System.Collections.Generic.List does not contain a definition for 'Should' and no extension method 'Should' accepting a first argument of type System.Collections.Generic.List could be found (as you missing a using directive ot an assembly reference?)"

Comment: I believe FactAttribute is part of xUnit... which test framework are you using?

Comment: there is a link in my question https://gist.github.com/ReitenSchnell/5998938

Comment: Yes, and that doesn't have any `using` directives, so we can't tell what test framework it was using. But you should know which test framework *you're* using, because you should have references to it.

Comment: thanks: **it was xunit**, I don't use test frameworks (never have) I just probably could have commented it out but I just want to test this code atm not go all the way - anyway my comment to the answer by Denis is the way to do it, thanks for your help I couldn't have figured it out without you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `using FluentAssertions;` statement at the top. If you're unsure about the correct references, remove any physical instances of `FluentAssertions.*dll` and add the corresponding Nuget package.

Comment: thanks dennis, the answer was `PM> Install-Package xunit -Version 1.9.2` and then `PM> Install-Package FluentAssertions` followed by a `using FluentAssertions;` (which **isn't** prompted for in the refractor) the refractor will prompt for `using Xunit;` tho.. NB: it was not "warehouse" as I assume in the OP) it was Xunit.

Comment: incidentally how could I rewrite `priorityCollection.TestList.Should().ContainInOrder` **without** FluentAssertions? I don't actually understand what that line is doing? :-s

Comment: It does exactly what it says: asserting that all items in `TestList` appear in the same order as they exist in the collection provided to `ContainInOrder`.